# Url.Action() does not remove default values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have rather a simple routing map.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{seoName}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, seoName = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Now, If use `Url.Action("Index", "Home")`, it does not properly remove defaults values of the route. And it gives me `/Home/Index`.

Now, if I remove either `{id}` or `{seoName}`, and its corresponding default value, then the URL is properly generated like `/` (root).

What I am missing here? It does not seem to be an ambient value, since I am visiting the main page with no ids, nor seoNames.

Any ideas?

Comment: Only the last parameter can be marked `UrlParameter.Optional`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Did not realize that, interesting. Please answer the question to accept it.

Comment: Nkosi has already added one :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need multiple mappings to achieve what you want as you are only allowed to make the last route placeholder optional.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "SeoFriendly",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{seoName}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", seoName = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```